# finally block in async method does not always run

Tags: c#, async-await, webapi

Consider this method that is called from a WebAPI controller

```
//WebAPI Controller 
    public async LetsDoThis() {
       await _logic.Method();
    }

//logic class
     public async Task Method()
     {
         try
         {
             await DoSomething();
         } 
         finally
         {
             await AlwaysDoThis();  //Will not always run
         }
    }
```

I am seeing a lot of instances where the code in the finally block is not being executed.  At first I thought this was due to `OperationCancelledException` being thrown but that does not seem to be the case.

What are likely causes for the code in the finally block to not run? (this is happening a lot so it is not an uncommon thing like the server crashing)

Comment: I can't reproduce this and I don't believe that this example represents the behavior that you are seeing. This standalone example absolutely calls the finally block when an `OperationCanceledException` is thrown.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include your source code as a working [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others.

Comment: Based on comments, I have modified the question

Comment: What is `DoSomething()`, and does *it* complete ever? If not: no, the `finally` won't spontaneously invoke itself - it needs to be triggered by the async callback

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What are likely causes for the code in the finally block to not run?

DoSomething() not completing.

Comment: Yup, seems the most likely. I would throw an honourable mention in for anything involving a dodgy sync-context, but: pretty sure web-API doesn't use a sync-context (unless OP has snuck one in)